# Do While connection loop

Tags: ansible

Let's say I have a list of N servers

- serverA
- serverB
- serverC

And I'm trying to initiate a ping against them in a loop but only while it's failing. Meaning if A is not responding, try B, if that is not responding go to C, etc. etc.

```
---
 - hosts: localhost  
     vars:  
       temp:  
         - serverA
         - serverB
         - serverC
     tasks:
     - name: Include loop
       include_tasks: pingLoop.yml
       with_items: "{{ temp }}"
       loop_control:
         loop_var: inner_var
       until: ping.ping == "pong"
```

pingLoop.yml

```
- name: Check connection
  win_ping:
  register: ping
  delegate_to: "{{ inner_var }}"

- name: Debug
  debug: var=ping
```

it doesn't work because apparently until doesn't work with include_tasks and I dodn't know how else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the use-case: "In a playbook, proceed with the first host connected."

Use *wait_for_connection* instead of *ping*. It's more practical, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
serverA ansible_host=test_99 ansible_user=admin
serverB ansible_host=test_98 ansible_user=admin
serverC ansible_host=test_11 ansible_user=admin
```

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - wait_for_connection:
            timeout: 5
        - set_fact:
            connected: true
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            connected: false
    - set_fact:
        srv_conn: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|zip(_conn)) }}"
      vars:
        _conn: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                   map('extract', hostvars, 'connected')|
                   list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  srv_conn:
    serverA: false
    serverB: false
    serverC: true
```

Next, in the same play, use this dictionary and add the first connected host to the new group *active*. Then, start new play with this group, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        srv_active: "{{ (srv_conn|dict2items|selectattr('value')|first).key }}"
      run_once: true
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ srv_active }}"
        groups: active
      run_once: true

- hosts: active
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Active host is {{ inventory_hostname }}
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [serverC] =>
  msg: Active host is serverC
```

---

Q: *"**Is making a group out of the server the best way?**"*

A: The next option might be to proceed on the controller, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        srv_active: "{{ (srv_conn|dict2items|selectattr('value')|first).key }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: true

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Active host is {{ srv_active }}
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Active host is serverC
```

Comment: Is making a group out of the server the best way?
Not sure if I made it perfectly clear in the OP, but esentially I'm just trying to connect to the first reachable host.

Not like... get all reachable hosts from a list, if that makes sense :) In any case, thank you for help!

Comment: You're welcome! No, you didn't make it clear. This was the reason why I solved the case ``"In a playbook, proceed with the first host connected."``. Others might be interested in an efficient procedure on how to select connected hosts. This answer doesn't solve your problem If you insist on sequential hosts' testing.